# Why im not getting the real current char i clicked/selected?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code:

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                if (mouseisup == false)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = "";
                    int positionToSearch = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                    richTextBox1.SelectionStart = positionToSearch;
                    textBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(positionToSearch, 1);
                    previousChar = positionToSearch;
                    textBox2.Text = "";
                    mouseisup = true;//add this statement
                }
                else
                {
                    currentChar = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
                    if (currentChar > previousChar + 2 || currentChar < previousChar - 2)
                    {
                        richTextBox1.SelectionStart = currentChar;
                        textBox2.Text = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(currentChar, 1);
                        button1.Enabled = true;
                    }
                    mouseisup = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private void richTextBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox2.Text == "")
            {
                mouseisup = true;
                button1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            string[] text = Parse_Text.ParseText(richTextBox1.Text, textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
            {
                richTextBox2.Text = text[i];
            }
        }
```

I created for the test a text new text file and entered the text file:

"Daniel > is smaller >< then daniel or Daniel depend on the D > but < <>"
Then in the program first click was on the first D of the first Daniel the second click was on the second D of the second Daniel.

Then in the new class in parse_text in this code :

```
List<string> parsedText = new List<string>();
            string[] entries = null;
            int startIndex = text.IndexOf(startTag);
            if (startIndex >= 0)
            {
                int endIndex = text.IndexOf(endTag, startIndex);
```

startIndex is 0 but also endIndex is 0. But endTag is the second D it shouldnt be index 0.
So thats i also a problem.

Comment: Smaller example: I have this: "daniel is here and bigger > then the small one < but now im > then him" If i click on the t of the then it should make a block of text from aniel is here and bigger > then the small one < but now im > but since there is a char > after the word bigger it will make the text: aniel is here and bigger . Why does he make the text with the first char and not in the place i clicked on ?

Comment: I have just tested your code and everything works as expected. 

If you put a breakpoint on the line where you get the position you'll see that it returns `172`, which is the position of the `<` before `title`. 

Where do you get the idea that it's taking the first appereance of the character? Do you make a search afterwards on the character?

Comment: Koen i just updated my question with the full code and the class where i parse the text after i select the start and end point. The Parse_Text class seems to be ok. The problem is somewhere in Form1. Try to use this text as i did.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>                   First click on the D then click on < of the title when they both appear in the textboxes click the button to parse it and see it wont get the whole text between it.

Comment: Click first time between the ! and the D then second time click between the > and < thats how im doing it and not getting the whole text in between.

Comment: Your update revealed the problem. ;-) Check my answer for a (possible) solution.

Comment: Koen ok i will look at your solution but im updatiung something in my question i did.

Comment: Koen just updated my question with another problem since this problem now throw an exception error since both indexs are 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you take an IndexOf of the character which will indeed give you the first occurence.
To avoid that, use the position of the character instead of the actual character.

You already have that information available on the line:

```
currentChar = richTextBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
```

**EDIT**

You should change your Parse_Text method for use with positions instead of characters.
On the top of my head you should get somehting like:

```
    public static string[] ParseText(string text, int startPos, int endPos)
    {
        List<string> parsedText = new List<string>();
        string[] entries = null;

        if (startPos >= 0 && endPos > startPos)
        {
            string images = text.Substring(startPos + 1, endPos - startPos - 1);
            entries = images.Split(new[] { ',' });
            for (var i = 0; i < entries.Length; i++)
            {
                entries[i] = entries[i].Replace("\"", "");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < entries.Length; i++)
            {
                parsedText.Add(entries[i]);
            }
        }

        return entries;
    }
```

Obviously you should add some extra tests regarding the allowed parameters.
For example:

- text cannot be string.Empty
- startPos cannot be less then zero
- endPos must be greater then startPos

Comment: I see your answer then what should i change ? Isnt this line take the position of the char ? And then i use this variable as position of the char.

Comment: Updated my answer with an example on how to use positions instead of characters.